# Configure IBM ACE 12 Toolkit to listen to IBM MQ queue and write to one

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to use ACE Toolkit so that it listens / reads from IBM MQ queue (Docker container, dev version, running locally).

Documentations instructs simply:

"You can use the Security identity property on the MQ node or MQEndpoint policy to pass a user name and password to the queue manager, by specifying a security identity that contains those credentials. The identity is defined using the mqsisetdbparms command."

How do I run "mqsisetdbparms" command, where can I find that command ?

I use Ubuntu Linux (for now).

Alternatively, can I test my ACE Flow so that I run MQ Manager (dev) kind of unsecured way, so that it does not expect user / password ?

Now I am getting error :

```
2023-01-03 20:57:07.515800: BIP2628W: Exception condition detected on input node 'MQFlow.MQ Input'. 
2023-01-03 20:57:07.515866: BIP2678E: Failed to make a server connection to queue manager 'QM1': MQCC=2; MQRC=2058.
```

.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mq-manager:
    container_name: mq-manager
    build:
      context: ./mq
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: ibm-mq
    ports:
      - '1414:1414'
      - '9443:9443'
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
#      - MQ_APP_PASSWORD=passw0rd
```

.

```
FROM ibmcom/mq:latest
```

Comment: In directory "ace-12.0.7.0/tools" there are 3 runnable files with name starting like mqsicreate*. But not "mqsisetdbparms".

Comment: The `mqsisetdbparms` should be in `server/bin`.

Comment: I guess you rather want your test integration server to listen for messages. The Toolkit is an IDE, that contains a test client, which can listen for messages, but that error messages comes from the integration server.

Comment: The mqsisetdbparms command can be run after you source the mqsiprofile script in server/bin. The mqsiprofile will set all necessary environment parameters to run mqsi commands, and it will add mqsisetdbparms along with other mqsi commands to the PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local testing, you can configure without usage of `mqsisetdbparms` like this:

1. Configure a policy in `$YOUR_ACE_WORK_DIR/run/DefaultPolicies/MQ.policyxml`:

   ```
   <policies>
     <policy policyType="MQEndpoint" policyName="MQ" policyTemplate="MQEndpoint">
       <connection>CLIENT</connection>
       <destinationQueueManagerName>QM1</destinationQueueManagerName>
       <queueManagerHostname>localhost</queueManagerHostname>
       <listenerPortNumber>1414</listenerPortNumber>
       <channelName>DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN</channelName>
       <CCDTUrl></CCDTUrl>
       <securityIdentity>MqIdentity</securityIdentity>
       <useSSL>false</useSSL>
       <SSLPeerName></SSLPeerName>
       <SSLCipherSpec></SSLCipherSpec>
       <SSLCertificateLabel></SSLCertificateLabel>
       <MQApplName></MQApplName>
       <reconnectOption>default</reconnectOption>
     </policy>
   </policies>
   ```
2. Configure a remote default queue manager and credentials in `$YOUR_ACE_WORK_DIR/overrides/server.conf.yaml`:

   ```
   remoteDefaultQueueManager: '{DefaultPolicies}:MQ'

   Credentials:
     ServerCredentials:
       mq:
         MqIdentity:
           username: 'admin'
           password: 'passw0rd'
   ```
3. Restart your ACE server

Comment: !!! !!! !!! !!! !!! !!!

Comment: I thought I accepted it? How do you do an "accept" `?

Comment: I tried to add "ftp" credentials for ACE to use as ftp-client. But ACE ftp does not use "ftp-policies" seems to me. FtpIdentity when used like MqIdentity above did not work.

Comment: There is a [FTP Server Policy](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=properties-ftp-server-policy-ftpserver). Did you define in the FTP policy xml the identity like this:`<fileFtpUser>FtpIdentity</fileFtpUser>`? Then it should work to define in group `ftp` this identity.